# Deployed Solution to Hololens But Can't Stop it

Tags: visual-studio-2019, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I deployed a basic unity program to Hololens; however I can't shut this program off. I closed out visual studio but it's still there.

How do I get the program to stop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, this answer is based upon using the Hololens 2.

1. Tap your wrist.
2. Hit the "house" button, this will close the Unity app.

Answer (score 1):

You can also force applications closed using device portal: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-windows-device-portal

It's in the apps tab and you click on the x next to the process.

When you exit the application using the start menu on your wrist the program is still stored in RAM and will resume when you open it again unless you press the x on the window in the HoloLens.